# Why is my .css page not being applied to my page?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to link a stlyesheet to my html doc, but it is not applying to my website. When I had the same css as an internal stylesheet, it worked fine but will not work as an external page. Attached is a screenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: Try link = "./style.css", also you have mispelled stylesheet as sylesheet.

Comment: You can try to set `href="../style.css"`

Comment: change `<link rel="sylesheet" href="style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try change with this way:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

change ***sylesheet*** to **stylesheet**

Comment: Wow, Cannot believe I did not see that typo. I swear I looked 80 times! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

`<head>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>`

`</head>`